# c++ debug segfault on linux/amd64 (assembler)

Tags: c++, assembly, gdb, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I try to debug crash of my application using core dump,
The part of back trace look like this:

```
#0  0x00000000000000a1 in ?? ()
#1  0x000000000065e8bf in TPageGroupBase::activate() ()
```

so as I understand there is some "wild" jump to
such address `0xa1`, looks like `this` have wrong value.
I look at disassembly of `TPageGroupBase::activate`, and get:

```
Dump of assembler code for function _ZN14TPageGroupBase8activateEv:
   0x000000000065e890 <+0>:     push   %r12
   0x000000000065e892 <+2>:     push   %rbp
   0x000000000065e893 <+3>:     push   %rbx
   0x000000000065e894 <+4>:     mov    %rdi,%rbx
   0x000000000065e897 <+7>:     mov    0xdb7e9a(%rip),%rdi        # 0x1416738 <_ZN11IPageWalker9instance_E>
   0x000000000065e89e <+14>:    mov    (%rdi),%rax
   0x000000000065e8a1 <+17>:    callq  *0x40(%rax)
   0x000000000065e8a4 <+20>:    mov    0x48(%rbx),%rbp
   0x000000000065e8a8 <+24>:    xor    %esi,%esi
   0x000000000065e8aa <+26>:    mov    %rax,%r12
   0x000000000065e8ad <+29>:    cmp    $0x1,%r12
   0x000000000065e8b1 <+33>:    seta   %sil
   0x000000000065e8b5 <+37>:    mov    0x50(%rbp),%rdi
   0x000000000065e8b9 <+41>:    mov    (%rdi),%rax
   0x000000000065e8bc <+44>:    callq  *0x68(%rax)
=> 0x000000000065e8bf <+47>:    cmp    $0x1,%r12
   0x000000000065e8c3 <+51>:    jbe    0x65e978 <_ZN14TPageGroupBase8activateEv+232>
```

**Update:** According to Jester (thanks) I should look at previous instruction as cause of wild jump.

So rebuild with debug symbols enable, restart tests and got crash again:

```
769         back_btn_->setVisible(val);
   0x000000000091c14d <+29>:    mov    0x50(%rdi),%rdi
   0x000000000091c151 <+33>:    mov    (%rdi),%rax
   0x000000000091c154 <+36>:    movzbl %sil,%esi
   0x000000000091c158 <+40>:    callq  *0x68(%rax)
```

back_btn_ is QSvgWidget(http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsvgwidget.html) and `QSvgWidget::setVisible` is virtual,

as understand `gas` manual at last instruction we have this:

```
p/x *(unsigned *)($rax+0x68)
 $7 = 0x141
```

as address for jump and this cause crash.

And I understand (thanks for comments), we here load address of virtual function, and

```
p/x *(unsigned *)($rdi+0x58)
$8 = 0x0
```

so looks like virtual address of object is null,
I thought that I do not init `back_btn_` somehow,
but:

```
(gdb) p back_btn_
$9 = (QSvgWidget *) 0x36fe3f0
```

and this address similar to other addresses for valid
objects, so somebody damage its content, and zeros its
virtual table, am I right?

Can I extract anything more from this coredump, any points?

Comment: It's showing the return address. The problem is with the previous instruction, `callq *0x68(%rax)`.  That is a jump through a pointer, probably a virtual method call.

Comment: The code calls a member function [function number 8, starting at 0] of the global variable `IPageWalker::instance`.  It then fetches some data at 0x48 into the first argument to `TPageGroupBase::activate`, and then 0x50 into that object. There is a pointer, probably, a vtable which we pick the 0x68 [13th element, starting at 0]. Which probably is incorrect in itself. Why is very hard to determine without understanding what the code is MEANT to do.

Comment: Thanks @MatsPetersson

Comment: If you can actively debug it and not just have a core dump, put a breakpoint where `back_btn_` is assigned. Check that the vtable entry is valid at that point and put a watchpoint on it so you can catch if somebody overwrites it. The thing is suspicious because vtable is normally read-only, so my guess would be that `back_btn_` itself is overwritten or is assigned an incompatible object. The vtable pointer in the object could be corrupted, too. PS: you should not use `unsigned` to print addresses because that's 32 bit only.

Comment: @Jester no, I can not actively debug, it is random crash, not reproducible with `-fsanitize=address` or under `valgrind`. I was just lucky today to get two random crash and one with debug info.

Comment: You can then try to verify vtable pointer, such as by doing `info symbol *(void**)back_btn_` which should give you something like `vtable for QSvgWidget + 16 in section .rodata of a.out`

Comment: @Jester thanks I will try

Comment: Not sure where `p/x *(unsigned *)($rdi+0x58)` comes from. I mentioned `p/x *(unsigned *)($rdi+0x50)` as the address of what we now know as `back_btn_`. But quite clear, there is something not right with that object (plausibly, of course, the problem is somewhere completely different, as it may well be overwriting the vtable or its pointer)